# Did MVVMCross support Shared Project?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to embedd MvvmCross into my Xamarin Shared Project, I add a view named **HomePage.xaml**, and add a binding viewmodel named **HomeViewModel**, also I add `Setup.cs` file and init code on platform project, but this issue came accross:

`MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Problem seen creating View-ViewModel lookup table - you have more than one View registered for the ViewModels: 2*HomeViewModel (HomeView,HomeView) ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: MvxFormsTemplate.ViewModels.HomeViewModel`

Does MvvmCross support Shared Project? If it worked, any template could be referenced?